# Why is Multiple Inheritance in Classes avoided?

Tags: c++

Is it because it is very confusing and sometimes fields get intermixed or some other reason? Its allowed is C++ but not in Java??

For Example:

herbivore and carnivore are derived from animal and omnivore is derived from both herbivore and carnivore. So won't some fields get mixed up.

Comment: Please don't shoehorn real world taxonomies into class hierarchies. That's way worse than whatever badness comes from multiple inheritance (I've been using multiple inheritance all over without remorse ever since I started learning C++; never ran into anything that made me reconsider).

Comment: Anyway, in your example, if you had to use MI then you'd just use virtual inheritance to solve the diamond problem.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: never had an issue with MI, ever? That's impressive.

Comment: @nneonneo You had an issue with it? I can mostly see issues that would be an issue with single inheritence just the same. I.e. _bad inheritence_

Comment: It's not so much "avoided" as "rarely needed". If you do need it, and to inherit from two classes with common base, you can choose whether to share the base ("virtual inheritance"), or duplicate it ("non-virtual inheritance"). It's quite complicated, but your tutorial should explain it.

Comment: Note that the difference between Java and C++ to this respect it not that huge... really only whether only one or multiple bases can have data members. Think interfaces.

Comment: And method implementations, i.e. behaviour?

Comment: I'd suggest reading through http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/ (which discusses the C3 linearization, an algorithm for doing multiple inheritance right, in use in Python 2.3+, Dylan, Parrot, and Perl 6, but *not* C++, which uses a much more naive/wrong approach). That link discusses some of the subtleties and gives examples of traps that naive implementations of multiple inheritance can fall into.

Comment: @sehe: when I was still learning C++, MI would often blow my mind and result in bad things when experimenting. I think it makes more sense now, though I can't claim I'm done learning C++ by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Skimmed over the article, I might need to revisit it again, but what are the *trap* that the more *naïve* implementation of multiple inheritance in C++ falls into? I am not sure whether the proper term for C++ MI would be *naïve* or rather *manual*. C++ does not attempt to linearize the inheritance chain for overriding purposes, but rather leaves that to the programmer. Or maybe I am missing the crux of the issue :)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Heh. I'm actually a C developer from back in the day who never did do C++. On some investigation into C++'s mitigation approach, it _does_ look adequate, even if some effort is involved in its use.

Answer (score 1):

It is not avoided at all in C++. `std::iostream` uses multiple inheritance and is part of the standard classes. It's pretty hard to write a non trivial program without using it (think about std::fstream or std::stringstream).

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/basic_iostream/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/basic_fstream/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/basic_stringstream/

Comment: I'm gonna downvote for this because `iostream` has one of the worst designs known to man.

Comment: Also, cplusplus.com is probably not the best place to link to.

Comment: I'm gonna upvote it, because this dude didn't write iostream.

Comment: @DeadMG The OP asked why MI is avoided. My answer is that it is not. iostream having a good design is another question.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is Multiple Inheritance in Classes avoided? Is it because it is very confusing and sometimes fields get intermixed or some other reason?

Multiple inheritance is often avoided because it leads to several problems which can be difficult to fix for a novice programmer. Possible problems:

1. [Diamond inheritance.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem)
2. Carelessly Inheriting multiple interfaces (which weren't carefully designed) can pollute object's "public" or "protected" section with methods that aren't that useful for this particular object.
3. You have to be aware of construction/destruction order when object inherits several other objects, otherwise you might get crashes due to undefined behavior caused by things like double-delete. In other words, If object C inherits objects A and B, and `~A` somehow uses something provided by object B, then `~A` should be called before `~B`. I.e. in this scenario `class C: public B, public A{}:` will work, but `class C: public A, public B{};` will crash when destroyed. Bug like this can be hard to find.

> but not in Java??

Ask java question for that.

> Its allowed is C++

Multiple inheritance is available in C++ because it is useful.

Typical scenario - there are couple of abstract interfaces your class has to support. Let's say "IReader", "IWriter" and "IUglyObject". Which have no common ancestor.
To support several interfaces without multiple inheritance, you'll either have to make sure all your interfaces have common ancestor (which isn't always possible) or you'll have to define extra classes (derived from interfaces you want to support), write a lot of glue code that forward calls from your class to derived classes, which is too much typing. With multiple inheritance you can simply protected inherit all your interfaces and add few methods that return pointer to required interface.

```
class MyClass: protected ISomething, protected ISomethingElse{
public:
    ISomething* getSomethingInterface(){ return this;}
    ISomethingElse* getSomethingEkseInterface(){ return this;}
protected:
};
```

> herbivore and carnivore are derived from animal and omnivore is derived from both herbivore and carnivore. So won't some fields get mixed up.

There are many ways to design hierarchy of classes, and the method you used in this example is not perfect. I could, for example, abstract "eating behavior" class and store it in "animal". That would allow me to change animal behavior on the fly and temporarily turn rabbits carnivores. Or I could create virtual method that either returns list of food types the animal accepts (or tests if the food is acceptable by this animal), that would allow me to make an animel that wants to eat only fried eggs and nothing else. There are other ways.

Class hierarchy doesn't have to mimic real world, you know...

> when I was still learning C++, MI would often blow my mind and result in bad things when experimenting.

If you're new, then avoid it for now. Multiple Inheritance is useful in the scenario I listed - class supporting multiple different interfaces without writing glue code. In all other cases it can be avoided and probably isn't necessary.

If language has a feature, it doesn't mean you have to use this feature.
If language has a feature with bad reputation, doesn't mean you should never use it.
Choose your tools based on situation.

Comment: Languages which don't support MI often have a different mechanism for supporting interfaces. They're a special case.

Comment: @MarkRansom: As far as I know, C++ doesn't have "other" mechanism for supporting interfaces. So people can either write glue code, or use multiple inheritance, or wait 20 years till C++ standard committee invents such mechanism (and then 5 more years till every compiler starts supporting it)..

Comment: My highest voted answer is "How to write an interface in C++" so believe me I know what you're talking about. I'm just saying that using interfaces as an example of why multiple inheritance is OK is kind of missing the point.

Comment: @MarkRansom: "My highest voted answer" That's a very bad/flawed argument, IMO. "using interfaces as an example" That's the main scenario I know when multiple inheritance is useful. I'm not saying that's the only way to do it. "why multiple inheritance is OK" There are situations when it is more useful than other tools, and there are situations where other tools are more useful. I don't think it qualifies as "OK" for all situations.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Explanation regarding your "my highest vote answer" Upvotes indicate how many people thought your question is worth clicking a button. They do not measure knowledge or post quality, although number of upvotes correlates with your knowledge / quality of your post in 50% of cases.